# why does my img stretches enormously only on Apple devises

Tags: html, css, ios, image

The is an img surrounded by a couple of divs. it look fine on my windows pc on different browsers, it is great on my phone. However, on apple devises it stretches to huge length. Even if i go to my website though google chrome on iPhone it is still stretched.

Also I al using bootstrap. So some classes are coming from there.

```
<div style="width: 80px" class="mx-auto" id="about-link">
    <a href="#about-link">
        <p class="text-center" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0.6rem; margin-top: 4rem; text-decoration: none; ">О нас</p>
        <div class="w-100" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <img style="width: 40px; height: auto; max-height: 100%;" src="img/icons/down.png">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

No other css used. Only the one embedded into my html.

I am thinking maybe it's something to do with what apple OS is based on. Because if not - then why would it still not work on google chrome on apple devises...?
Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend you do the following:
1) First check actual size of the image in any image viewer. Привет :)
2) Second start removing lines of code in style section of an image one by one:
2.1. Remove max-height, hard refresh
2.2. Remove height, hard refresh
2.3. Remove width, hard refresh
Then you will know what is causing the problem

Comment: Since you have a width set, maybe you also need to set a specific `height` instead of `max-height`

Comment: @Undry Привет) What should I do I don't have a device yo check and modify my code from the browser on?